# Sysmon itself I am trying to establish connections to the internet

Tags: networking, http

I've installed Sysmon latest version on multiple servers and as I add sysmon-modular config to the sysmon, sysmon process tries to establish connections to the internet which is odd. Some of these IPs are also suspicious.

I don't know why this happens.

[image]

Comment: Why are the IPs suspicious?

Comment: In this picture, IP addresses are not suspicious but I have Syn-Sent to 93.184.220.29 from sysmon on another server which is reported in Alienvault OTX and other TI repositories. My main question is that why sysmon is trying to connect external IPs?

Comment: This would appear to be a Windows internal question more than a security question. First confirm if this is expected behaviour (a Windows question) then if unexpected, you have a security issue.